# javascript check if array key is set

Tags: javascript

```
var place = []

place[0] = "Sant Marti de Canals";
place[1] = "Catalonia";
place[3] = "";
place[4] = "Spain";

placeTitle = place.join(",");
```

current output is "Sant Marti de Canals,Catalonia,,,Spain"

how can it be "Sant Marti de Canals,Catalonia,Spain"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing your own code for this can help

```
var place = []

place[0] = "Sant Marti de Canals"; place[1] = "Catalonia"; place[3] = ""; place[4] = "Spain";

var placeTitle ='';
for(var test in place) {
    placeTitle += place[test]!=''?place[test]+',':'';
}
placeTitle = placeTitle.substr(0,placeTitle.length-1)
```

Comment: and then remove the `,` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define a filter function, which is useful in many other situations.

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(p) {
    var a = [];
    p = p || function (x) {return x;}
    for (var i = 0; i<this.length; ++i) {
        if (p(this[i])) {
            a.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}

...

placeTitle = place.filter().join(', ');
```

Comment: I don't need to. The empty string gets converted to `false`, so it isn't included in the result array. What I don't account for (since it isn't necessary in this case) is `0`, which (were it present) would also be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

```
placeCopy=[];
for(var i=0;i<place.length;i++){
  if(typeof place[i] != 'undefined' && place[i].length > 0){  
    placeCopy.push(place[i]);
  }
}
placeTitle = placeCopy.join(",");
```